# Issues with replacing/updating files in tableau

Tags: replace, tableau-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlSEv.png)

I'm a new tableau user, so please bear with me as I try to formulate my question.

I just ran my 1st set of monthly reports this week and there were a lot of reds and exclamation marks that came up that I noticed we had to manually fix. My coworker, who is also new to tableau, has just gotten used to fixing these errors but I'm trying to figure out why it is the same issue for every single file we are uploading into tableau. Basically, we are replacing/updating about 13 reports every month with new data in Tableau, but it's just not a smooth and automatic process as in the YouTube videos. We are having to go back in and either replace references or Tableau is trying to find a link between the reports or some calculation field is invalid.

To my understanding, all of this should update automatically as long as we have the same info (fields) each month, right? My coworker is fine just fixing those errors every month but there's gotta be a way to actually automate this process. My coworker also said that tableau is very glitchy. A way of saying that is just the way it is with the software, which I have a hard time accepting. This thing costs my company $800 per person!

All we are doing in Tableau is replacing the previous months reports to get new numbers. Also, we are taking over someone else's work in tableau so could it be that the original file had a different set of data and that is why we are having all these errors come up each time we're adding the new data?
At this point I'm trying to see if I can just recreate last month's tableau report and add this month's to see if we still get those errors. Is that even possible?
So can anyone recommend any videos on things that can go wrong when replacing a file in Tableau?  Does anyone have a suggestion on what to do? While YouTube is very helpful, most don't cover issues that might come up when replacing a file, except for replacing references or fixing a calculation field.
Thank you so much for your responses!

Comment: Tableau is not glitchy.  And it's not clear what these "errors" are that you're seeing.  You shouldn't have to recreate anything in Tableau.  If you have a monthly report, you should just limit the data in the report to the last month, or create a parameter where the user can select which month to run the report for and then the report doesn't need to be recreated.  It **sounds** like your lack of familiarity with how to work in Tableau is the issue, but no one here can give you a definite answer to your question because we have no specific details.

Comment: Perhaps take one "error" and use it as an example for your question.  Tell us what's happening, what you're doing to fix it.  I also suggest you work on your Tableau knowledge.  They have a solid knowledgebase, community, courses, tutorials, conferences and workshops.

Comment: Hi Devlin, thanks for your comment. I'm uploading a new spreadsheet each month with new data that I get from a different software. Unfortunately that software isn't connected to tableau. It looks like I can't add a screenshot here so I will edit my original comment to add an image. Like I said in my original post, I'm having to either replace references, change a formula for a calculation field, change a number to a date or a string or vice versa as tableau no longer recognizes it once I upload the new file. It's only when I do that,  all the reds go away.

Comment: Do you have the ability to upload data to a database?  Or connect Tableau to the database of that "different software".  Spreadsheets tend to be poor data sources because they often lack data integrity / formatting checks.  And Tableau may have to "guess" what the data type is on a column in a spreadsheet based on just the data in that particular file, but then the next month, it could be possible that the new data doesn't fit the data type Tableau guessed.  Again, this doesn't sound like an issue with Tableau.  It sounds like an issue with how you're attempting to use Tableau.